# using a sound sensor to catch a specific noise a saw motor makes before choking up?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, filtering, signal-processing, sensors

I'm needing help with finding a sound sensor of some type or directional microphone that will help me detect a specific sound that a saw motor gives off when it's about to get choked up? Also in the same location there are over 50 motors running at the same time this saw is, so it's very loud in the area. I'm needing a device that can handle all this noise and still be able to detect the saw noise to shut down the motor before it messes up? I'm struggling to find a device so i can find the right micro controller to do the dsp?

Comment: Even though there are 3 question marks in your post, there are no questions.

Comment: You might try asking this over at the electronics.stackexchange , as this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and find one sound file or a YouTube video and download the video.

You download videos by doing something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?=example

Then changing it to https://www.youtubepp.com/watch?=example

Then use the mp3 file by making it into an mp3 by using the website